# Circling area on map / drawing a circle on a map

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, editing, software-recommendations, circle

I'm trying to find a map of the US East coast, with cities, that I can draw a circle, say of 150mi radius, so I can plan a road trip from my hometown. As far as I can tell, I can't do this on Google Maps or OpenStreet Maps. This seems to me to be the most basic of operations, so there just must be something I'm overlooking, or searching for incorrectly.

I would prefer a web-based map, because I'm just brainstorming, but I don't mind downloading a mapping application on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. I even tried printing downloadable maps for use with a compass, but none of them printed a map scale, or it wasn't accurate (Google).

What am I overlooking? Is there some reason this can't be done?

Comment: Why did you find it necessary to edit my question?

Comment: This is why your question was edited: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing circles on a webmap, which in almost all cases is projected in WebMercator (`EPSG:3857`) is problematic as it does not represent real-world distances, but severley distorts distances, see e.g.: https://www.independent.com/2017/06/14/map-rap/

A good solution would be creating geodesic buffers with a GIS-software as [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/) (OpenSource). See [Approximating Geodesic Buffers in QGIS](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis/).

Using [Google Earth](https://www.google.com/), you can use the measuremt tool and select the `circle` option (see screenshot below). Measurements are ellipsoidal distances, not planimetric ones, so it gives more or less accurate results even on a planetary scale. Use the North Korean missiles example linked above to test the result: it will return correct measurements, including the whole US-West-coast (see 2nd screenshot).

[image]

[image]